# Google Maps adding marker from ajax using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to add google maps to my web page, the web page has div with id of radar with width specified. I get coordinates from a second page using jquery ajax method, and plot them on the map using Marker. But only the last marker is displayed nothing else is displayed.

```
var global = new Array();
        $(document).ready(function () {

            console.log("ready!");
            if ($("#StartingDate").val() != "") {
                var start = $("#StartingDate").val();
                var end = $("#EndingDate").val();
                var id = $("#UserId").val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: "GetData.aspx?StartingDate=" + start + "&EndingDate=" + end + "&UserId=" + id, async: false, success: function (result) {
                        var resp = result.split(",");
                        for (x = 0; x < resp.length - 1; x++) {
                            var cor = resp[x].split(";");
                            var lat = cor[0];
                            var lon = cor[1];
                            var date = cor[2]
                            var temp = [lat, lon, date];
                            global.push(temp);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }


        });
        $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {

            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 4,
                center: myLatlng
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("radar"), mapOptions);
            for (var i = 0; i < global.length; i++) {
                console.log(global[i]);
                var marker =  new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(global[i][0]),parseFloat(global[i][1])),
                    title: global[i][2]
                });

                marker.setMap(map);
            }

        });
```

After the ajax call succeeds my variable named global is filled like this:

```
global = [
 [
   0: "33.622835",
   1: "73.062932",
   2: "16/06/2015 1:17:24 AM"
 ],....
];
```

Comment: What does `console.log(global[i]);` return in your for loop? Another thing: why do you create the map on ajaxComplete? Have you tried creating the map before (in document ready for example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** Turns out you have to set the `.ajaxComplete` handler before you make the `ajax` request since you have set `async` to `false`.
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/xpso3jn1/) is a working example.

I would suggest saving the markers in an array if you intend to use the markers later on(i.e.: move them, or remove them).

<s>Only the last marker is displayed because you override it every time. What you need to do is save the marker in an array.</s>

What i would do is create a function `addMarker` which creates a marker with the given coordinates and a title and returns it. 
This would look something like this:

```
function addMarker(title, x, y, map){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(x,y),
        map: map,
        title: title
    });

    return marker;
}
```

This function should be called where you currently are setting the marker in the for-loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < global.length; i++) {
    console.log(global[i]);
    markerArray[i] = addMarker(global[i][2], global[i][0], global[i][1], map);
}
```

`markerArray` needs to be a global array like `global`.

Comment: While it's a good idea to put your markers in an array, you don't **have to** and you don't explain why you should. Further to that, this will not change anything to the problem described.

Comment: @MrUpsidown Putting the marker inside an array helps because you create multiple markers instead of overriding it every time for-loop is executed. Since OP has a for-loop in his code I assumed it is trivial why it helps. And yes it should solve the problem. I have use the code I posted for an app and it worked for me.

Comment: nope it does not work..still display a single marker

Comment: @Timo No. It will not solve the problem. Creating `var marker` in a for loop is not the issue here. And btw, this is exactly what your function does. The only difference is that your code is wrapped in a function and you put the created markers in an array. Nothing else.

Comment: My bad, I should have tested the code before posting an answer. Turns out it doesn't work because `async` is set to `false` and the `.ajaxComplete` handler is created after the `ajax` request already finished. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/xpso3jn1/) is a working example.